# Application Insights causing w3wp to crash

Tags: azure-application-insights

Running AI 2.4, using the AppInsights Monitor app, on Windows Server 2012 R2, monitoring a public-facing (publishing) SharePoint site.

Every so often, w3wp crashes (throws up a "*do you want to debug this?*" dialog), and the following is recorded in the event log:

```
Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

Message: Type is not resolved for member 'System.Diagnostics.Activity,System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

StackTrace:  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.HostingEnvironmentShutdownInitiated(String appId, HostingEnvironment env)
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.RemoveThisAppDomainFromAppManagerTableOnce()
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownInternal()
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownWithoutDemand()
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ShutdownAppDomain(String stackTrace)
at System.Web.Compilation.DiskBuildResultCache.ShutdownCallBack(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

It looks like I'm running into this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/613.

I've placed the System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource (version 4.5) DLL into the inetserv directory, and I've updated the web.config to do an assembly redirect. However, the crash still occurs.

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsSource 4.5.0 (the one with the fix) has Assembly version 4.0.3.0.

And from your exception, it seems you are still using

> System.Diagnostics.Activity,System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.2.0

Please check your bindings redirect and check if you still reference 4.4.0 somehow. You can also enable [fuslog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) to see a detailed binding error info.

Comment: It looks like I was referencing the wrong assembly version; redirecting to 4.5.0 rather than 4.0.3.0. Also, I had to replace the DLL inside of the bin directory of the IIS site; the one in the inetsrv directory didn't seem to make a difference. Thank you!